# Is it possible to add OS Open Carto vector tiles to QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, vector-tiles, ordnance-survey

I am interested to learn whether it is possible to view Ordnance Surveys OS Open Carto vector tiles in QGIS - I am using QGIS 3.4.2.

The data I would like to add can be found [here](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=7b93af6cf12947baa9351e9dd12f82b5), and I have tried to use the [Vector Tiles Reader](https://github.com/geometalab/Vector-Tiles-Reader-QGIS-Plugin/blob/master/README.md) plugin to connect using the URL provided on the ArcGIS tiles server.

When I try this I get an error saying "*The field 'vector_layers' is required but not found. This is invalid TileJSON*"